# Nexus 4 not recognised by Windows 7 machine after KitKat update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a Nexus 4, which I used to be able to connect to my Windows machine via USB, to test my code on. When I plugged it in, if I tried to run an application on it from Eclipse, Eclipse would tell me that there were no devices, and ask me if I wanted to start a virtual device, unless of course I waited a bit, until Windows popped up a dialog box asking me if I wanted to treat the Nexus 4 as a directory for photos, or audio, etc.

Now however, Windows never gets to the point of showing me that dialog box, so Eclipse will always tell me there are no connected devices. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user. But from similar questions I've read, it might be necessary to re-install the drivers. Are you just unable to access the device, or is it not detected at all? Have you checked your Windows device manager for "unknown devices"? Do you get any popup when connecting it?

Comment: Can you see 'Nexus 4' listed in Device Manager under 'Portable Devices'? Mine was initially listed under 'Other Devices' with a yellow warning symbol until I installed the drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers solves the issue. The strange part is that before I uninstalled the drivers, the name on the driver said it was for a Samsung Galaxy device, which the Nexus 4 clearly is not.